# Activity crash suddenly in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am developing an app in android which contains listview with images, webviews, many common views which we use in daily app. My app works properly, but when I run it 3 or 4 times it crashed suddenly from current activity and goes to previous one. I don't know why. It doesn't give any exception or error. And I start that activity again 3 or 4 times it works proper and crash again. Anybody tell me why it'd be happened. Might be memory management.

Majorly It crashed in listview activity. But if it crashed using data loads on listview, it has to be give an exception. I have also used thread, imagesloader, viewholder. But cannot find what's the prob!

Adapter of ListView is:

```
public class SavedAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
JSONArray jsonArraySaved;
JSONObject jsonObjectSaved;
String user_id = "", distance = "";

public SavedAdapter(Context context, JSONArray jsonArraySaved) {
    this.context = context;
    this.jsonArraySaved = jsonArraySaved;       
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return jsonArraySaved.length();
}

@Override
public JSONObject getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        return jsonArraySaved.getJSONObject(position);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public GothicBoldTextView textViewFullName, textViewDistance;
    public GothicTextView textViewHeadLine, textViewTags;
    public ImageView imageViewPhoto;        
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View rawView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (rawView == null) {
        rawView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.featured_events_list_item3, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.textViewFullName = (GothicBoldTextView) rawView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewFullName);
        viewHolder.textViewHeadLine = (GothicTextView) rawView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewHeadLine);
        viewHolder.textViewTags = (GothicTextView) rawView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewTags);
        viewHolder.textViewDistance = (GothicBoldTextView) rawView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewDistance);
        viewHolder.imageViewPhoto = (ImageView) rawView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageViewPhoto);
        rawView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rawView.getTag();
    }
    try {
        jsonObjectSaved = getItem(position);
        if (jsonObjectSaved.has("distance")) {
            distance = jsonObjectSaved.getString("distance");
            viewHolder.textViewDistance.setText(AccessClass
                    .getDistance(distance));
        }
        if (jsonObjectSaved.has("profile")) {
            jsonObjectSaved = jsonObjectSaved.getJSONObject("profile");
            if (jsonObjectSaved.has("firstname"))
                viewHolder.textViewFullName.setText(jsonObjectSaved
                        .getString("firstname"));
            if (jsonObjectSaved.has("lastname"))
                viewHolder.textViewFullName
                        .setText(viewHolder.textViewFullName.getText()
                                + " "
                                + jsonObjectSaved.getString("lastname"));
            if (jsonObjectSaved.has("headline"))
                viewHolder.textViewHeadLine.setText(jsonObjectSaved
                        .getString("headline"));
            if (jsonObjectSaved.has("tags")) {
                String tags = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonObjectSaved.getJSONArray("tags")
                        .length(); i++) {
                    tags += jsonObjectSaved.getJSONArray("tags")
                            .getJSONObject(i).getString("name")
                            + ", ";
                }
                viewHolder.textViewTags.setText(tags.substring(0,
                        tags.length() - 2));
            }
            if (jsonObjectSaved.has("avatar_thumb")) {

                if (!jsonObjectSaved.getString("avatar_thumb").equals(
                        "/avatars/thumb/missing.png")) {
                    viewHolder.imageViewPhoto.setTag(jsonObjectSaved
                            .getString("avatar_thumb"));
                    SplashActivity.imageLoader.displayImage(context
                            .getResources().getString(R.string.domain)
                            + jsonObjectSaved.getString("avatar_thumb"),                                
                            viewHolder.imageViewPhoto);

                } else if (!jsonObjectSaved.isNull("picture_url")) {                            
                    viewHolder.imageViewPhoto.setTag(jsonObjectSaved
                            .getString("picture_url"));
                    SplashActivity.imageLoader.displayImage(
                            jsonObjectSaved.getString("picture_url"),                               
                            viewHolder.imageViewPhoto);
                }
            } else if (jsonObjectSaved.has("picture_url")
                    && !jsonObjectSaved.isNull("picture_url")) {                    
                viewHolder.imageViewPhoto.setTag(jsonObjectSaved
                        .getString("picture_url"));
                SplashActivity.imageLoader.displayImage(
                        jsonObjectSaved.getString("picture_url"),                           
                        viewHolder.imageViewPhoto);
            } else {                    
                viewHolder.imageViewPhoto.setTag("null");
                viewHolder.imageViewPhoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.photo2);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    rawView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                Intent intent;
                intent = new Intent(context, PublicProfileActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("public_profile_id", ""
                        + getItem(position).getString("id"));
                context.startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    rawView.invalidate();
    return rawView;
}
}
```

Comment: This is extremely difficult to answer without more information. Can you show code you think is problematic? Describe what you've done to trace it down?

Comment: Thanks for response. I have mention my adapter code of listview. But it's working properly.

Comment: It does not give any logcat error.

Answer (score 0):

i think you might

```
adapter.imageLoader.clearCache();
adapter.imageLoader.stopThread();
listView.setAdapter(null);
```